# C++ game. Error code when compiling. Error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Okay.. This may be a stupid question. I just followed a tutorial on how to make a game engine. I have been fighting my way through several errors, and i finally think i'm getting into the last errors. So here is my errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_MessageBoxA@16 referenced                 in function __catch$_wWinMain@16$0
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Engine::Engine(void)" (??0Engine@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   _wWinMain@16
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall Engine::Go(void)" (?Go@Engine@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
>
> Error 4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

**Code:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Engine.h"

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Engine* engine = new Engine();

    try
    {
        engine->Go();
    }
    catch(char* e)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, e, "Exception Occured", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

So i kinda guessed that it is the wWinMain thing, i have made.But what the problem is, is unclear to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It must be very bad tutorial if it throws char* as exception...

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/230524-c-tile-engine-from-scratch-part-1/

Comment: Error 1 sounds like you arent linking against "user32.lib"

Comment: Fixed that error. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__MessageBoxA@16 referenced in function __catch$_wWinMain@16$0
```

This error indicates you need to link your project against user32.lib.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Engine::Engine(void)" (??0Engine@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Engine::Go(void)" (?Go@Engine@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wWinMain@16
```

These errors indicate you need to compile and link Engine.cpp into your project.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please describe how to link to the user32.lib?
And should i do: "#include "Engine.cpp"?

Comment: @user2007556 http://bit.ly/19sKOgF

Comment: No, do not `#include` Engine.cpp. Just add it to your project's Source Files.

Comment: Bam! I got the user32.lib added. Sorry for asking about that. I was just lazy, i guess. Wait a second. I'm going to try the Engine.cpp now.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/8877e16c70c4e8ae8c98ca6c2701e36d It should work?

Comment: It couldn't be a wrong installation of SFML?

Comment: @user2007556 You still get only the same two errors?

Comment: Yeah. The first error is gone, because i added the user32.lib.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/24aa27b51a552c102efaa42829c1537a Here is a picture of the project.

Comment: @user2007556 Show Engine.cpp.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/eea27c15fdc9f242c39a79ae0c798368

Comment: @user2007556 No, that's Engine.h. Or at least, that's what Engine.h should look like. Engine.cpp should look different. Refer to the tutorial.

Comment: Wait. I may have copied something. Stupid me! Let me change it.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/ee87cff4a87994b326645dc0883ab496 It removed the errors, and gave me new ones.

Comment: I may know how to resolve these. I really don't want to bother you with it. Thanks for all your helpful answers!